# Bootrstrap in Express.js with LESS: include bootstrap folder in public/lib/?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, express, less, pug

I am totally a beginner in Express.js, and I am trying to build a simple website using Express,js, Jade and Less. The way I created my folder project is:

```
 $ mkdir myProj
 $ cd myProj
 $ express --sessions --css less
```

Recently I heard about bootstrap, and I would like to include it in my project. I tried to find online tutorials on how to add and include bootstrap, and the way I tried to do this is:

```
 --> download bootstrap from the official page
 --> add the downloaded folder in public/lib/bootstrap
 --> include the css files in the layout.jade as follows: link(rel='stylesheet', href='/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')
```

As far as I can see it is working. But I am not sure if this is the right way to include bootstrap in Express.js. Is there any other way to include bootstrap in Express.js and is my way correct?

Comment: if you want bootstrap less files download it from here -> https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$ npm install -g twitter-bootstrap-node

# Create the project: (Default css engine is "less",And template engine is "jade")

$ twitter-bootstrap project
$ cd project
$ node app.js
```